# Creating a doodle box on every even page in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using word to develop a workbook for a class I am going to teach.  I want every even page (ie the left hand side of the book once it is bound) to have the same space made up of three boxes.  It will really just be formatted doodle space.  I've tried to use the footers on every even page to create this effect.  It looks great but there is one line of text that should just transfer over to the next page which keeps showing up.  Is there are better way to format this and make the text automatically continue onto the next odd page and not in the boxes I've created?

Comment: Are you printing double sided? Do you want it on the right side of left pages (where it's bound)? How is the page setup? Are you using columns?